# Classic vs new view and using the share button

Tags: share, item-level-permissions

Clicking Share in the Classic view or New view produces 2 different results, not only revolving around the gui.

**Share in classic view**
[image]

**Share in New view**
[image]

The permissions of the single file now present a difference. Both files have unique permissions, however

In the classic view I can clearly see listed the person I shared with

[image]

While in the new view I do not and I have to click 'Manage links' to see it

[image]

Under an End user perspective I believe the first one is still the easier one to understand and manage but I do realize that it is the 'old' way, can someone point out to me the benefits of the New view sharing method or why the single item permission view is an improvement?

Comment: It is unclear to me that you are using the modern UI or not? If you are using modern UI then you can get all the details via share dialog itself. See this image https://imgur.com/F7qzbRc

Comment: That's not what I meant and your image shows the path to get to the permissions page, not the actual permissions of the single item. My screen shots are of the permission page